# Setting the initial value of useState with async function using contextAPI and React

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-context

I am very new to react and I have been struggling to understand how to fix this. I wrap my whole around a context API and then I use the value to check if a user is logged in. But because of HOC, the initial value of the `const loggedIn`  is already rendered before the request is gotten from the server.
When the program starts I get undefined and I understand why I am getting but don't know how to fix it.
I have researched a lot but haven't found a clear solution.

```
function AuthContextProvider(props) {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);

    async function getLoggedIn() {
        const loggedInRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/loggedIn");
        setLoggedIn(loggedInRes.data);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getLoggedIn();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

My question now is how do I set the initial value of this `const loggedIn` before my program renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is good, you just need to wait for loggedIn to be ready before rendering:

```
function AuthContextProvider(props) {
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);

async function getLoggedIn() {
    const loggedInRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/loggedIn");
    setLoggedIn(loggedInRes.data);
}
useEffect(() => {
    getLoggedIn();
}, []);

if (!loggedIn) {
   return (
      <AnotherComponentThatDontRequireAuthentication />
   );
}

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
        {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
```

}

Comment: If i return null, then the whole application will not be rendered. Because the AuthContext Provider is wrapped around the while app.

Comment: If you need to provide a different behaviour, then you can return another component that don't need the AuthContext Provider. I've updated my original response.

Comment: Thanks based on the idea you provided I was able to make it tweak and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Resulting Code

```
function AuthContextProvider(props) {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoadig] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/loggedIn").then((response) => {
            setLoggedIn(response.data);
            setIsLoadig(false);
        });
    }, [loggedIn]);

    if (isLoading) {
        return < div > App is isLoading</div >;
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```